# How to cross import TypeScript classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, export

Im trying to rewrite JavaScript code to TypeScript, but I'm running into some problems when trying to import a class into a different TypeScript file.

This used to be done with jQuery Namespaces, where it worked fine.

My situation is:

file Layouts:

```
import { Commands } from './funnel.commands'
var commands = new Commands(); /*<--- problematic line*/

export class Layouts {

    loadHtmlSubLayout(done: Function, layoutname: string): void {
    /*...*/
        commands.CloseSubLayout();
    /*...*/
    };

    closeSubLayout(layoutContent): void {
    /*...*/
    };


}
```

file Commands:

```
import { Layouts } from './funnel.layouts'
var layouts = new Layouts();

export class Commands {

    GotoLayout(el, cmd: CommandObj): void {
       /*...*/
        layouts.loadSpecificLayout(layouts.onLayoutSwitched, layoutName);
    };
    CloseSubLayout(): void {
    /*...*/
        if ($subLayoutContent.length !== 0) {
          layouts.closeSubLayout($subLayoutContent);
        }
    };
}
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get the error 'Commands is not a constructor'. How can I make sure this works without having to move the methods around?

Comment: You are importing A in B and B in A... What in the name of god are you doing?

Comment: Its not my original code thankfully I'm just rewriting it for the company, obviously the example is simplified, but with the jQuery version it kinda makes sense

Comment: @HagelslagPakje I was wrong, cyclic dep cause problem in runtime.

Comment: Yes, like I already said, its got to do with the fact the one class imports another and vice versa, just need some help fixing it without moving all the code

Comment: @HagelslagPakje This could be resolved using TS namespace too. But how do you want to use these to file? If you intend to use strict module, then have to do some refactoring.

Comment: Namespaces are deprecated, don't use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of these 2 module has to back-off and use async/lazy init the other in order to break the circular import chain.

In your example, I assume `Commands` is used ahead of `Layouts`. So you can do the following:

file `funnel.commands`

```js
import { Layouts } from './funnel.layouts'
var layouts = new Layouts

export class Commands {
  CloseSubLayout(): void {
    layouts.closeSubLayout({});
  };
}
```

file `funnel.layouts`

```js
import { Commands } from './funnel.commands'
var commands: Commands
setTimeout(() => {
  commands = new Commands()
})

export class Layouts {
  loadHtmlSubLayout(): void {
    commands.CloseSubLayout();
  };

  closeSubLayout(layoutContent): void {
    console.log('You just called Layouts.closeSubLayout()')
  };
}
```

other party:

```js
import { Commands } from './funnel.commands'

var commands = new Commands()

commands.CloseSubLayout()
```

---

Above solution should work, but circular dependency is still an anti-pattern. Since you're rewriting a codebase, better refactor that part. I suggest use some sort of dependency injection pattern.

file `dependencies`

```
export const dependencies: any = {
  _register(map: any) {
    Object.assign(this, map)
  }
}
```

file `funnel.commands`

```
import { dependencies as dep } from './dependencies'

export class Commands {
  CloseSubLayout(): void {
    dep.layouts.closeSubLayout({});
  };
}
```

file `index`

```
import { Commands } from './funnel.commands'
import { Layouts } from './funnel.layouts'
import { dependencies } from './dependencies'

var commands = new Commands()
var layouts = new Layouts()
dependencies._register({ commands, layouts })
```

Comment: That's a really nice way to explain dependency injection!

Comment: Where i have to declare/import  index (index.ts) ? is it required to import ?